# navigateToURL sending data via POST to php page

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

Imagine that I have a form in a flash application with two fields, input1 and input2. And when the user finish filling this form, it goes to a php page.
At the moment, I'm using the `$_GET` method to send the data.
Like this:

```
var request:URLRequest;
request = new URLRequest("http://site.com/page.php?data1="+input1.text+"&data2="+input2.text);
navigateToURL(request);
```

And in the php code:

```
$_GET["data1"];
$_GET["data2"];
```

But this way, the information stays in the URL. How can I send this via `$_POST`?

Comment: Hi CEAFDC, what have you tried so far?
The Stack Overflow Community  might be able to help you figure out the problem
but is not able to without concrete data and this is not a "write me some code" type of site.
Help us help you, by sharing the code you're using right now, possibly some sample data and any possible errors you encounter.
Adapt your question to include those and you'll surely get a helpful answer. Thanks for considering. :)

Comment: well it's not a "quid pro quo" thing before you get help around here but it'll make sure that your questions get answers and that people can help you at all. We can't look at your code and errors can be quite esoteric or duplicitous at times. The best way to help us help you is to be as specific as you can with regards to errors and options/code you tried. Thanks for considering.

Comment: Hey @Gonzo do you have any of hitting a url like this but not navigating to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in AS 3 the [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) class you use to specify your request has a [method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#method) property which can be used to set he HTTP option for submission method, you'll need to set it to POST using [URLRequestMethod](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html) constant [POST](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestMethod.html#POST) for perfect form or you could use a "POST" string.

You can find a [comprehensive example](http://snipplr.com/view/4487/) on [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/)

so in a nutshell:

```
var url:String = "http://localhost/myPostReceiver.php";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
var requestVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
requestVars.foo = "bar";
// ... fill in your data
request.data = requestVars;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
// after this load your url with an UrlLoader or navigateToUrl
```

When using Adobe Air You'd need to use the [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) class instead of [navigateToURL()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29) because of the following tidbit:

> Parameters
>       request:URLRequest — A URLRequest object that specifies the URL to navigate to.
>
> **For content running in Adobe AIR, when using the navigateToURL() function, the runtime treats a URLRequest that uses the POST method (one that has its method property set to URLRequestMethod.POST) as using the GET method**.

Basically whenever you want to use POST set method correctly, as also indicated by the documentation for [navigateToUrl](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29):

next in php you'd be receiving the variable in the superglobal [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array, where you could access it as such:

```
<?php
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
/* $foo now contains 'bar'
   assignment to another value is not necessary to use $_POST['foo'] 
   in any function or statement
*/
```

Comment: Is this still the case with AIR? I need to send post data when opening a browser and I'm using a AIR.