# How to login a user through their browser from AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm working on an AIR app that logs a user in to a remote website. At certain points during the session the user may need to open a page in their browser. When they do that they are not logged in according to the browser so the user must login again. I'm trying to login them in through the browser when they login in the application.

I've read that AIR can manage cookies. I think it's doing that but I'm not sure. Is there a way to share cookies with the browser? Is that what manage cookies setting does?

If none of that is happening could I create a mx:HTML instance or stage web view and double login with that? A stage webview should be using the system browser correct? The same browser that will launch when `navigateToURL()` is called.

**UPDATE:**
It looks like cookies [are shared](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2010/08/single-sign-on-and-http-cookies-in-air-applications.html) across browsers except in a few cases such as Firefox and Linux. Update again, cookies are [shared less](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2011/01/more-on-sharing-http-cookies-with-air-applications.html) often than initially thought. It looks like I might be able to login a user by creating a StageWebView instance. I will have to double check to make sure it's a default browser and not the internal webkit.

UGH. It looks like StageWebView on the desktop uses the [internal webkit](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#includeExamplesSummary). There is a useNative property though. But even if I can use a native system browser I'm not sure how to log someone in with it because I don't think I can post to it? I think I can only set the URL which would be a get...

...It looks like I can create a post request and then use navigateToURL() to load that [request](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#data). It would be hacky but it might work.

ARG. It looks like AIR doesn't [support post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174007/441016) through navigateToURL().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want to complicate things by thinking just to use `POST` ?! You can use `GET` by sending some temporary identifier ( token, hash, ... ), like some websites do with their user's newsletter when they give you the possibility to log in just by clicking a simple link in that newsletter, which will be generated by your server side script after that your user has been successfully identified, then when the user opens that link in the browser you can verify that information and then create your cookies ...

Hope that can help.

Comment: That might work. I have a application that logins to WordPress. When the user wants to go to their WordPress site they have to login again. If it's possible I will try and see if there is a token I can use. Is it a cookie I can then send in a GET call?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts The token is just some "information"(s) generated by a server side script ( to be used once for a very limited time, it's just a temporary info stored in the DB for example as a user's session info, ... ) which will be verified when the user use that link in the browser. I did find a WP [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autologin-links/) which did the same thing as what I meant, but in all cases, you have to secure that process to avoid security issues ...